# how to resolve "The hostname should be a domain name, not an IP address"

Tags: email, web, server, dns, spam

I am using dodaddy domain as addon domain in bluehost and using only emails of this domain.. but my emails are going in spam folder.

I tested it on mail-tester it shows this result.

[image]

This is my DNS configuration

[image]

Comment: You need to change HELO string, in your mail server configuration

Comment: where can I find it? and change with what?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you did there but here's solution : 
if your domain name is abc.com and you want your email something like contcat@abc.com
just go to email option and create 1 email. and then you can use 1 of the 3 provided webmail browser or can redirect all the emails to your Gmail account.

hope it helps if not do comment.

Comment: no buddy.. i dont want to redirect it to gmail.. simple is my emails are going in gmail spam folder instead of inbox, thats the problem